# Travis + Matrix deploy to multiple aws buckets

Tags: matrix, amazon-s3, travis-ci

I wonder how I set matrix with dual deployment.

here is logic

```
language: node_js
node_js:
  - 8
cache:
  yarn: true
matrix:
  include:
    - env: MHTD=USER1
    - env: MHTD=USER2
install:
  - if [ "$MHTD" = "USER1" ]; then yarn build-web:"$BUILD_NAME"; fi
  - if [ "$MHTD" = "USER2" ]; then yarn build-web:"$BUILD_NAME1"; fi
```

So now I have a logic but I don't know how to set deployment step. I want to push two different builds to 2 different s3 buckets. How I can do that?

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Matrix expansion per build stage is an open [feature request](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/8295) for travis-ci currently. A workaround is to manually specify multiple stages with differing inputs, like from [this example](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/build-stages/warm-cache/):

```
cache: bundler

jobs:
  include:
    - stage: prepare cache
      script: true
      rvm: 2.3
    - stage: test
      script: bundle show
      rvm: 2.3
    - stage: test
      script: bundle show
      rvm: 2.3
```